# How to remove or hide specific sections of Page-Builder?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

How to remove or hide specific sections of Page Builder? I don't want tabs and divider sections in the layout menu and element so ho we can remove or hide them in Magento 2

check the screenshot

[image]

any way to achieve this?